# Why "+" is parsed differently depending on whether it is on `path` or `query` part of a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I am not sure whether this behavior is specific to any framework or not. I was on a rails project.
Consider the following request
`http://localhost/some_path/some+value`
Here `some+value` is parsed as it is. No encoding.
Now for the next request:
`http://localhost/some_path?params=some+value`
`some+value` was parsed as `some value`

My question is what are the reason for this behavior and does it compliance with [rfc1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) and [URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-serializing)

Comment: "Parsed" where? Do you mean by the time it ends up in the `params` in the controller?

Comment: @MattGibson Yes exactly.

Comment: Long story short: urls legacy.
URL and Query params have to be encoded differently - more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33939287/1904052

Now, rack is handling that for you so you can expect it to be like that on any framework that uses rack ('ensurance' here -> https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/ea9e7a570b7ffd8ac6845a9ebecdd7de0af6b0ca/test/spec_utils.rb#L44 )

Answer (score 0):

The relevant spec for URIs is RFC 3986.

RFC 3986 does not mandate the structure of the query string. That depends essentially on how HTML forms work, and that's why "+" is special in the query string, but not anywhere else.